# Android LVL device specific licensing

Tags: android, google-play, android-lvl

I am working on an application which needs to be licensed on individual device basis, meaning that different devices have to purchase separate license even if they are used by the same user (using the same account). Is this something supported by Android LVL? Initially I thought it could be accomplished by using DeviceLimiter. But after looking at the code, I think it only gives you a way to limit how many devices can share the same license. If I set it to one (basically my server would check to see how many devices are associated with the userId provided by LVL as an argument to DeviceLimiter), the user can only use the license on one device. But that's not exactly what I want, I would like the user to purchase multiple licenses for different devices. But since Google LVL is tied to user account, there is no way for me to check which license is for which device.

Anyone has done this before? Is it possible with LVL? Was my understanding of DeviceLimiter correct? Many thanks!

Comment: Just to add the API for DeviceLimiter
Policy.LicenseResponse isDeviceAllowed(String userId);
which only takes userId string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [**In-app Billing**](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_overview.html) with unmanaged products. That way your license could be purchased as many times as required.

Managed products can only be purchased once per Google account the same as standard apps.

You would need to include a "BackUp\Restore License" function in  your app as unmanaged products are gone forever if the app is uninstalled or the phone is reset.

Comment: Thanks, Kuffs! I was hoping that I don't have to go down that road :-) I have not worked with in-app billing before, so I will take a look at it. Any good tutorial or article that you can recommend? particularly on unmanaged products?

Comment: I've just implemented it myself and it wasn't difficult using only the standard docs. If you have a server you can call on you may also be interested in droidactivator. http://code.google.com/p/droidactivator/

Comment: Droidactivator sounds interesting. Did you use it in your project? What's your experience with it? I also saw there is a library wrapped around what google released. https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary Have you looked at it before? Thanks!

Comment: No not used it myself. The billing library looks interesting.